# DoCmd.OpenReport Frm, acViewNormal not working after vbYes Then.. why?

Tags: ms-access, vba

i would like to have two msg boxes yes/no. The first one for saving the form and the second one for printing. Although the following code is working:

```
Private Sub CmdPrint_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenReport Frm, acViewNormal
End Sub
```

It's not working within a yes/no MsgBox, it seems that the information is not parsed.

I'm not a programmer, but I like to learn it, probally it's bad on all sides :D

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

  If MsgBox("Je staat op het punt de ingevoerde gegevens op te slaan." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Weet je zeker dat je dit formulier wilt opslaan?", vbYesNo, "Gegevens opslaan") = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.Save
  Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
  End If

  If IsNull(Me.WrkOrdr) = True Then
    Me.WrkOrdr = Val(Nz(DMax("[WrkOrdrNr]", "WrkPlts"), "0")) + 1
    ''# or   Me.txt2BookNumber = CLng(Nz(DMax("[BookNumber]", "Participant"), "0")) + 1
  End If

  If MsgBox("Je staat op het punt dit formulier uit te printen." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Weet je zeker dat je dit formulier wilt uitprinten?", vbYesNo, "Formulier printen") = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport Frm, acViewNormal
  Else
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you stepped through the code - set a breakpoint by pressing F9 on a line of code, press F8 to run each line ? When you do, does frm have a value? You can check by hovering over it, or by typing ?frm in the immediate window (ctrl+G to toggle immediate window). It should return a string, because report name must be a string. I would suspect that you mean either frm.Name or Me.name, if you had not already said that your original test worked.

BTW for this :

```
 If IsNull(Me.WrkOrdr) = True Then
```

Why not use this:

```
 If IsNull(Me.WrkOrdr) Then
```

Also, I would not rely too much on:

```
DoCmd.Save
```

And:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
```

The default for Access is to save and there are a couple of things that will stop undo from working in the way you expect.

Comment: ok thank you, i'm a complete noob to vba, what would be a better sollution.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks right.

Try adding

```
Dim ans As Integer
ans = MsgBox("ja of nee?", vbYesNo)
MsgBox ("ans=" & ans & " vbyes=" & vbYes & " vbno=" & vbNo)
```

and see what the result is